# Windows Mobile 6.0

Tags: windows-mobile

i am trying to debug my application and i have used the following code...
but whenever i try to debug the application i get the above error....

> Error 1 Deployment and/or registration
>   failed with error: 0x8973190e. Error
>   writing file
>   '\Windows\NETCFv35.wm.ARMV4I.cab'.
>   Error 0x80070070: There is not enough
>   space on the disk.Device Connectivity
>   Component  not only with
>   "NETCFv35.wm.ARMV4I.cab" it happens
>   with different dlls at different
>   times...

code is as follows

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Facebook;
using Facebook.Entity;

namespace WindowsMobileFacebookDemo
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {


        Facebook.API.FacebookAPI fbAPI = new Facebook.API.FacebookAPI();

        public Form1()
        {            
            InitializeComponent();

            fbAPI.IsDesktopApplication = true;
            fbAPI.ApplicationKey = "00b0a669821ecbb4a646f822fdb56ffe";
            fbAPI.Secret = "1b185cd1951cc7eb8bc28fdec7adb664";

            string savedAuthToken = fbAPI.AuthToken;
            fbAPI.CreateSession(savedAuthToken);
            string savedSecret = fbAPI.Secret;
            string savedSessionKey = fbAPI.SessionKey;        
        }
    }
}
```

Please i have already tried releasing the references by

```
1.changing the Property Copy Local to False
2.trying to reset the emulator
3.uninstalled and reinstalled the
a. Microsoft Virtual PC 2007
b. Microsoft Active Sync
c. Windows Mobile Professional Emulator 6.0 and standard as well
4.tried to change the active sync
5.Deleted the Programs and stopped the running programs from the emulator
```

Thanks in Advance do we have any other solution that will remove the errors

Comment: You might not want to be publishing your keys here....

Comment: Show us a capture of the entire deployment log - so every file that gets pushed down.  I have a hunch, but need that to confirm.

Comment: So can u let me know how exactly we can get the logs for the debugger...Also i have tried all the Facebook Toolkits version 1.0 to 3.01,but the problem that arises in each and every API is the Space ..

Answer (score 1):

I also get this problem when using the Emulator. From the deploy log I can see that VS deploys almost all the .net dependent files, and I don't know why, its like VS goes crazy.

Until someone come up with a solution, maybe you can do like me and only fix the symptoms.

1. Delete all the deployed windows dll:s, check your deploy folder.
2. Change so all the dependent projects deploy to the same folder, to minimize the disk space.
3. Lastly I don't use the emulator.

Comment: The "why" is because you probably have a desktop assembly referenced somewhere in your project (possibly by accident), so Studio tries to push all of the dependencies down, which won't fit.  The solution is to remove and re-add all of the References, making sure no desktop assemblies are referenced.

Comment: Ok, and I guess the reason it doesn't happens all the time is because I don't deploy that particular project every time. That makes sense. I will surly look in to that! Thanks.

Comment: @giZm0: No need to get surly about it.